# Customizing columns in a Gridview using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, gridview

As a programming enthusiast, I have tried to replicate some code [from a video I found](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPtQFRXvaXw).  The form uses LINQ to SQL to bind data from a hosted shared database to a Gridview.  The page works fine until I create some C# code in the code behind that is very similar to what I saw in the video. Transaction_ID is the primary key and the data table. I have watched the video at least a dozen times and cannot identify my problem.  I have seen some similar issues on this site but have not yet found a solution for me. If I use selection method 1 the gridview populates, but not when I used method 2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{

    DataClasses2DataContext db = new DataClasses2DataContext();

    var q = from t in db.Transactions

            //selection method 1
            //select t;

            //selection method 2
            select new
            {
                //ID2 = t.Transaction_ID,
                Date = t.Date,
                Type = t.Transaction_Type,
                Group = t.Group,
                Name = t.Name,
                Effective_Session = t.Effective_Session

            };

    e.Result = q;
}
```

}

Here is the ASPX code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataKeyNames="Transaction_ID" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">

</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="DataClasses2DataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
    onselecting="LinqDataSource1_Selecting" TableName="Transactions">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is a piece of the dbml code:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Transactions")]
public partial class Transaction : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new           PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

private int _Transaction_ID;
private string _League;
private string _Season;
private string _Session;
private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _Date;
private string _Effective_Session;
private string _Team;
private string _Transaction_Type;
private string _Group;
private System.Nullable<double> _Round;
private System.Nullable<double> _Pick;
private System.Nullable<double> _Overall;
private System.Nullable<double> _Player_ID;
private string _Name;
private System.Nullable<double> _F15;
private System.Nullable<double> _F16;
private System.Nullable<double> _F17;
private System.Nullable<double> _F18;
private System.Nullable<int> _F19;
private System.Nullable<double> _F20;
private System.Nullable<int> _F21;
private System.Nullable<int> _F22;
private System.Nullable<double> _F23;
private System.Nullable<double> _F24;
private string _F25;
private System.Data.Linq.Binary _upsize_ts;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnTransaction_IDChanging(int value);
partial void OnTransaction_IDChanged();
partial void OnLeagueChanging(string value);
partial void OnLeagueChanged();
partial void OnSeasonChanging(string value);
partial void OnSeasonChanged();
partial void OnSessionChanging(string value);
partial void OnSessionChanged();
partial void OnDateChanging(System.Nullable<System.DateTime> value);
partial void OnDateChanged();
partial void OnEffective_SessionChanging(string value);
partial void OnEffective_SessionChanged();
partial void OnTeamChanging(string value);
partial void OnTeamChanged();
partial void OnTransaction_TypeChanging(string value);
partial void OnTransaction_TypeChanged();
partial void OnGroupChanging(string value);
partial void OnGroupChanged();
partial void OnRoundChanging(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnRoundChanged();
partial void OnPickChanging(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnPickChanged();
partial void OnOverallChanging(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnOverallChanged();
partial void OnPlayer_IDChanging(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnPlayer_IDChanged();
partial void OnNameChanging(string value);
partial void OnNameChanged();
partial void OnF15Changing(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnF15Changed();
partial void OnF16Changing(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnF16Changed();
partial void OnF17Changing(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnF17Changed();
partial void OnF18Changing(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnF18Changed();
partial void OnF19Changing(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnF19Changed();
partial void OnF20Changing(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnF20Changed();
partial void OnF21Changing(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnF21Changed();
partial void OnF22Changing(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnF22Changed();
partial void OnF23Changing(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnF23Changed();
partial void OnF24Changing(System.Nullable<double> value);
partial void OnF24Changed();
partial void OnF25Changing(string value);
partial void OnF25Changed();
partial void Onupsize_tsChanging(System.Data.Linq.Binary value);
partial void Onupsize_tsChanged();
#endregion

public Transaction()
{
    OnCreated();
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="[Transaction ID]",     Storage="_Transaction_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public int Transaction_ID
{
    get
    {
        return this._Transaction_ID;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Transaction_ID != value))
        {
            this.OnTransaction_IDChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._Transaction_ID = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("Transaction_ID");
            this.OnTransaction_IDChanged();
        }
    }
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_League", DbType="NVarChar(255)", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public string League
{
    get
    {
```

Here is the error:

```
DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType1`6[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
    [System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, 
    mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, 
    Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with the name 'Transaction_ID'.
```

Comment: Do you have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true` on your `GridView`?

Comment: It sounds like there is a logic error in your query condition. If you could post an example of the rest of your query?

Comment: Yes AutoGenerateColumns is set to true.  This is the entire query.  I have included the entire code behind file.

Comment: Without looking at the markup and database it's very hard to guess whats wrong. But I would strongly suggest to go through Scott Gu's blog, specially this one:[LINQ to SQL (Part 9 - Using a Custom LINQ Expression with the <asp:LinqDatasource> control)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx). You will see similar method is implemented here.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look as soon as I can make time.  The video I have been referring to is based on this blog.  Would it help me if I add the the page code and part of the dbml file to my question?

Comment: I hope so! If you send me your project, I can take a look - if you don't mind!

Comment: I edited my question by adding some more of the project.  I hope I haven't over done it.  I printed out the Scott GU blog that you mentioned.  I will keep you posted if that can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your code works when you uncomment this line?

```
//ID2 = t.Transaction_ID,
```

If you are going to pick and choose which values from the datasource you're going to show, you need to go ahead and set up the colums in the GridView markup (and set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`).

Your columns collection (in the GridView declaration) would look something like this:

```
<columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Group" HeaderText="Group"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Effective_Session" HeaderText="Effective Session"/>
</columns>
```

Comment: No I get the same error message with or without the transaction_ID.  I was able to get a gridview with the aspx code but I am attempting to do more customization in the code behind as I saw in the video.